# Choose page size when print XPS files from IE7

Tags: xps-viewer

When I open an XPS file in IE, I would like to print to a 11x17 page.  When I click "Properties" of the printer, and choose 11x17, the print area on the 11x17 is still 8.5x11.

I've also tried "File->Page Setup", but it is grayed out.

Does anyone know how to change the page size when printing XPS files?